# CNN: TypeError: Expected int32, got list containing Tensors of type '_Message' instead

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

When I try to train CNN method with Tensorflow, I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./train.py", line 87, in 
l2_reg_lambda=FLAGS.l2_reg_lambda)

TypeError: Expected int32, got list containing Tensors of type '_Message' instead.
```

How can I fix it?

This is my code:

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    session_conf = tf.ConfigProto(
      allow_soft_placement=FLAGS.allow_soft_placement,
      log_device_placement=FLAGS.log_device_placement)
    sess = tf.Session(config=session_conf)
    with sess.as_default():
        cnn = TextCNN(
            sequence_length=x_train.shape[1],
            num_classes=2,
            vocab_size=len(vocab_processor.vocabulary_),
            embedding_size=FLAGS.embedding_dim,
            filter_sizes=list(map(int, FLAGS.filter_sizes.split(","))),
            num_filters=FLAGS.num_filters,
            l2_reg_lambda=FLAGS.l2_reg_lambda) (line 87)
```

Answer (score 0):

`x_train.shape[1]` return a `Tensor` and it's value is not calculated until `sess.run()`, so you should pass a int32 value instead of shape[1].

Comment: This code: sequence_length=x_train.shape[1] referring to this code self.input_x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, sequence_length], name="input_x"). Should I change that code?

Comment: I think pass `sequence_length` in ` self.input_x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, sequence_length], name="input_x")` to `cnn = TextCNN(         sequence_length=sequence_length`